# radius of convergence of hypergeometric function

Tags: divergent-series, hypergeometric-function

Looking up information on the [Bessel function](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/06/02/01/01/01/) there is a formula as $|z| \to \infty$:

$$ I_0(z) \approx \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} {}_2F_0( \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2z}) = \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\tfrac{1}{2})_k(\tfrac{1}{2})_k}{k!}\frac{1}{(2z)^k} \right] $$

The infinite series on the right doesn't seem to converge anywhere, it's radius of convergence is $0$.  Is it possible to recover a value using [borel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation)?

---

**COMMENT** The series I have written above terminates and is therefore *wrong*.  Either it could read:

$$ I_0(z) \approx \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} {}_2F_0( \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2z}) = \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^\color{red}{\mathbf{n}} \frac{(\tfrac{1}{2})_k(\tfrac{1}{2})_k}{k!}\frac{1}{(2z)^k} + O\left( \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \right) \right] $$

If we try to complete the infinite series, I believe the radius of convergence is $0$, which is why I ask about Borel summation.

$$ I_0(z) \approx \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} {}_2F_0( \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2z}) = \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^\color{gray}{\mathbf{\infty}} \frac{(\tfrac{1}{2})_k(\tfrac{1}{2})_k}{k!}\frac{1}{(2z)^k} \right] $$

Comment: The infinite series you have there on the right looks an awful lot like a finite series to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n$ in the summation index should be an $\infty$, and the series is meant to be interpreted as an [asymptotic expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion), where convergence is not a consideration.

Comment: John: see See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion